# distinction between Bayesian Network and another graph

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

I want to ask if we have two graph one of them Bayesian Network and the other one just regular graph, how we can distinction between them.

Comment: A Bayesian Network can be represented as a graph.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what a "regular graph" might be and how it would be presented or described to you?

Comment: @whuber I imagine "regular graph" in this case means "any other graph" as opposed to some technical term

Comment: @ssde Thank you, but I would like the OP to explain what *they* mean rather than hearing your guess about what they might mean.  Even "any other graph" is vague: are we talking about directed or undirected graphs? With or without labeled edges? Etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Bayesian networks directed, with information flowing in only on direction and asymmetrical? Thus:

1. if node i have a directed link to j, and j have a directed link to i then it ain't a Bayesian network,
2. If the network ain't directed then it ain't a Bayesian network
3. If you can start at a node and follow a path that loops you back to the node you started on then it ain't a Bayesian network.

I can only see test to falsify whether a graph qualifies as a Bayesian network or not. I don't think it I s possible to say for sure since any graph can have the same structure as a Bayesian network without being a Bayesian network. Whether a graph actually is a Bayesian network depends on the interpretation and the context (I.e. The code the network is processed by).

But if you have graph A and B. You know one of them is a Bayesian graph and the other not, then you can run the three tests above. If A fails, then B is the one and vice versa. If both A and B passes the test, then you have a problem.